# How to disable terminal feedback when writing password for sudo?

Tags: sudo

when I write my password on terminal for sudo command, it gives me writing feedback even if I didn't modify the sudoers file. How can I fix this? This is my situation:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to disable feedback, or why it was turned on in the first place?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is actually a change that was recently included in a round of updates to Loki. It is briefly mentioned in their new [blog post](https://medium.com/elementaryos/loki-updates-for-the-new-year-ff6b6ba65531#b9d4). A package called `elementary-default-settings` was updated to include a file located at `/etc/sudoers.d/pwfeedback`, which changes this behavior when entering a password in the terminal.

If you wish to disable the feedback, try this command:

`sudo mv /etc/sudoers.d/pwfeedback /etc/sudoers.d/pwfeedback.disabled`

This will keep the file around in case you want to re-enable it, which you can do with the following:

`sudo mv /etc/sudoers.d/pwfeedback.disabled /etc/sudoers.d/pwfeedback`

Comment: Thanks! :) I think it's highly irresponsible, to automatically enable password feedback - Why would I want to show anybody how many characters are in my password at all!?

Comment: Consider that elementary OS is targeted at users switching from macOS and Windows, who probably find the lack of feedback strange. In any case, exposing password length is much less of an issue than using a long password in the first place.

Comment: sorry for the late comment: thanks for the answer, works fine!

Comment: Amazing solution, even showing us by any chance we want to revert back. Thank you.